# Javascript closure: How to add dynamic baselayers to Cesium map

Tags: javascript, closures, cesiumjs

I am attempting to add multiple baselayers to a Cesium map from a set of values in a database.  I would like the javascript to just iterate over them and then add them.  Here is the static code example from Cesium:

```
var imageryViewModels = [];
imageryViewModels.push(new Cesium.ProviderViewModel({
     name : 'Open\u00adStreet\u00adMap',
     iconUrl : Cesium.buildModuleUrl('openStreetMap.png'),
     tooltip : 'OpenStreetMap (OSM)',
     creationFunction : function() {
         return Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
             url : 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/'
         });
     }
 }));

 imageryViewModels.push(new Cesium.ProviderViewModel({
     name : 'Black Marble',
     iconUrl : Cesium.buildModuleUrl('blackMarble.png'),
     tooltip : 'outlines of civilization',
     creationFunction : function() {
         return Cesium.createTileMapServiceImageryProvider({
             url : 'https://cesiumjs.org/blackmarble',
             credit : 'B Observatory',
             flipXY : true
         });
     }
 }));
```

Super simple so far with a set of values that are static.  Here is where it gets tricky, I want to loop over a set of values and then push the ProviderViewModels on to the array. Like this -

```
var imageryViewModels = [];
baseLayers = HashOfValuesFromDatabase;
for(int i=0; i<baseLayers.length; i++{

  imageryViewModels.push(new Cesium.ProviderViewModel({
       name : baseLayers[i].name,
       iconUrl : Cesium.buildModuleUrl(baseLayers[i].iconUrl),
       tooltip : baseLayser[i].toolTip,
       creationFunction : function() {
           return Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
               url : baseLayers[i].url   // ***** this value always the last value ****
           });
       }
   }));

}
```

The problem is that the javascript closure is causing me problems and every one of my imageryViewModels is the last value in the baseLayer.url object.  Cesium needs this to be a function here.  Is there a way to keep this a function but get the values of the iterated baseLayer.url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben Aston's answer is the correct approach here.  He didn't try running it, and there's an extra semicolon after the `}(i))` that's illegal inside an argument list, and there are also some problems he copy-pasted from your original question.  Here's the corrected version, and I did get this to run:

```
var imageryViewModels = [];
for(var i=0; i<baseLayers.length; i++) {

  imageryViewModels.push(new Cesium.ProviderViewModel({
       name : baseLayers[i].name,
       iconUrl : Cesium.buildModuleUrl(baseLayers[i].iconUrl),
       tooltip : baseLayers[i].toolTip,
       creationFunction : (function(i) {
           return function() {
             return Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
                 url : baseLayers[i].url  
             });
           };
       }(i))
   }));
}
```

The reason this fixes the `url` parameter is because of the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) that uses `i` as a parameter.  This creates a new JavaScript closure per iteration through the loop, which is expensive, but is required so that each individual `create` function gets its very own closure with its own copy of the value of `i` from that particular iteration of the loop.  Without this, there is only one closure with only one `i` variable, and by the time any of the create functions are actually called, the loop is long since finished and the value of `i` has reached its maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this (I haven't run it):

```
var imageryViewModels = [];
baseLayers = HashOfValuesFromDatabase;
for(int i=0; i<baseLayers.length; i++{

  imageryViewModels.push(new Cesium.ProviderViewModel({
       name : baseLayers[i].name,
       iconUrl : Cesium.buildModuleUrl(baseLayers[i].iconUrl),
       tooltip : baseLayser[i].toolTip,
       creationFunction : (function(i) {
           return function() {
             return Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
                 url : baseLayers[i].url  
             });
           }
       }(i))
   }));

}
```

Edit: correct syntax (thank you to emackey)